# Por que eu não consigo fazer um "append()" em uma lista formada a partir de um "join()"?

Tags: python, string, lista, append

Comecei criando uma lista no Python deixando cada elemento abaixo do outro através do `join()`. Depois, tentei adicionar um elemento na lista através do `append()`:

```py
abc = '\n'.join(['a','b', 'c'])
abc.append('d')
```

Entretanto, quando eu executo o código aparece o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Se não me engano o `append` serve para adicionar um item a uma lista, porém a função `join` retorna uma string e não uma lista, portanto o método não existe

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3):

O erro é justamente este que está escrito na mensagem de erro, interpretando ela já sabe o que ocorre.

No caso está criando uma *string* e guardando em `abc`, aí chama um método chamado `append()` nesse objeto, que ainda é uma *string*, e se for ver a [documentação do tipo `string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) verá que ele não possui esse método `append()`, portanto não pode chamá-lo. Tem que chamar só um dos existentes conforme a documentação, poderia só concatenar a letra ali, como já demonstrou saber fazer já que fez na linha anterior.

Talvez queria fazer outra coisa, mas a resposta para a pergunta feita é esta, até porque nem sabemos o que seria essa outra coisa.